# Empirical Risk formulation

Tags: unbiased-estimator

I am trying to get an intuitive understanding of the empirical risk below. Based on my understanding, we are unable to compute a function that minimizes the **expected risk** because we do not have access to the true underlying distribution i.e. we don't have access to all the training data in the world. We do however, have training samples that we can use to compute an estimate from, called the empirical risk.

From the photo below, since the expected risk is defined as

$R(f) = E_z(l(f,Z))$

where Z represents all the training data in the world, then the empirical risk is

$\hat R(f) = E_z(l(f,D))$ where D represents a subset of the training data. **My question is**, why do we take the expectation over $\hat R(f)$ and what does this mean ? From my understanding $\hat R(f)$ is the average of the losses over D, which is a scalar. Why and what does taking an average over a scalar mean ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your data is a random subsample (of size N) from the entire set of instances. So, the empirical risk you calculate on the subsample is only an estimate of the true expected risk (that is the one you would have calculated if you had access to all the training data).

The question then becomes is the empirical risk that you are calculating on some random subsample - a biased or unbiased estimate of the true expected risk?

---

In statistics, if you have some quantity $\theta$ that you wish to know, but you can only estimate this quantity approximately through some random observations and come up with an estimator $\hat{\theta}$, then the bias of this estimate is defined as,
$$\textrm{Bias}(\hat{\theta}) = \mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}] - \theta$$

We consider the estimator $\hat{\theta}$ to be unbiased if the above quantity is 0 [1]

---

To come back to the question we raised earlier, we wished to know if the empirical risk is an unbiased estimate of the true expected risk or is it a biased estimate. And to answer the question, one takes the expectation of the empirical risk, and it turns out at least in your attached picture that it does come out equal to the true expected risk and hence the empirical risk is an unbiased estimate of true expected risk.

**Why do we care whether the empirical risk is biased or unbiased?**

I am assuming that you are working in the area of machine learning. In that case, in most tasks, you are minimizing empirical risk to estimate $f$, say $\hat{f}$. If your empirical risk was a biased estimator of the true expected risk, then it is difficult to give guarantees as to whether your estimated function $\hat{f}$ will generalize to unseen data points. It is because the empirical risk is an unbiased estimator of the true expected risk, there are certain guarantees we can give about the fact that minimizing empirical risk also with high probability minimizes the true expected risk and hence your estimated $\hat{f}$ generalizes.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator

Comment: Thank you. And yes I am a student studying machine learning. But what does it mean to take the expectation of the empirical risk ? The empirical risk comes from a random subset of size N. To generate the expectation of the empirical risk, would I have to generate K random subsets of size N ? I think my main misunderstanding is that the dataset that I have of size N, can only return me 1 empirical error. So the expectation over the empirical error does not make any sense to me

Comment: Remember this analysis is done on an arbitrary dataset of N samples. So, these N samples are actually N random variables. The analysis is expected to hold for any N samples. So you shouldn't think like, "hey I have fixed N samples with me". Because these samples are not fixed values.